# Why are my different Land Cover NetCDF layers looking the same?

Tags: r, raster, spatial, netcdf

I am reading in several land-cover layers from the Copernicus dataset (NetCDF files) and trying to quantify the number of land-cover changes between one year of recording and the next.

However, the problem I run into is that all my years seem to be the same. This is especially weird as the layers from 1992 should be at least somewhat different to the ones from 2012 (for example), but they are not. I also have too many cells with NA values.

I don't know if I am reading them in incorrectly or where the problem stems from. (Here I have only included 2 layers but I am working with 29. I know the code is redundant in some places but I am only an intermediate R user. I checked the projection of the layers and the shapefile and they are matched).

This is my code:

```
#Load packages
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

#Load data
ncfile1992 <- "ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-1992-v2.0.7cds.nc"
ncfile2002 <- "ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2002-v2.0.7cds.nc"


#Rasterize data
nc_class_year <- list(ncfile1992, ncfile2002)
sst_rast <- list()
for (i in 1:length(nc_class_year)) {
        sst_rast[[i]] <- brick(nc_class_year[[i]], varname ="change_count")
        new_name <- paste0("sst_change_", 1991+i)
        assign(new_name, sst_rast[[i]])
}

#Load Norway shapefile
norway <- getData("GADM", country = "NO", level = 0) 

#Crop to Norway
change_layers <- list(sst_change_1992, sst_change_2002)
change_layers_norway <- list()
for (i in 1:length(change_layers)) {
        change_layers_norway[[i]] <- crop(change_layers[[i]], norway)
        new_name <- paste0("change_crop_norway_", 1991+i)
        assign(new_name, change_layers_norway[[i]])      
}

#Mask layers
norway_change_layers <- list(change_crop_norway_1992,change_crop_norway_2002)
change_layers <- list()
for (i in 1:length(norway_change_layers)) {
        change_layers[[i]] <- mask(norway_change_layers[[i]], norway)
        new_name <- paste0("norway_change", 1991+i)
        assign(new_name, change_layers[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `all.equal(` on your results to see if they are actually the same? Then I'd wonder about my name swapping approach that may or may not end up swapping values rather than changing the name, if that is even the goal. Hard to follow.

Comment: Yup, using terra: `all.equal(ncfile1992["change_count"] |> crop(norway), ncfile2002["change_count"] |> crop(norway), maxcell = 4760 * 9812)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: @Chris the lines in the for loops `new_name <- paste0("norway_change", 1991+i)
        assign(new_name, change_layers[[i]])` are just the only way I could find to save the created layers with a different name. When I run the loop with all my 29 layers (1992 - 2020) only the layers from 1992 to 2015 are the same, while 2016 -2020 are completely different to one another and the 1992-2015 layers.

Comment: [Docs](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/satellite-land-cover?tab=overview) as reference. `r["change_count"] |> crop(norway) |> values() |> table()` also shows exactly the same amount of values for 1992 and 2002. Ergo: No changes in LCC at all in 10 years. This can't be right. Your layers seem to be looking the same, because they are the same, but WHY?